# ReactJS window.addEventListener("hashchange") not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component called Home. Within Home, I have a function "urlListener" in which I have added an event listener to alert whenever the URL is being changed.

```js
var Home = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function () {
  return {
   openedFile: this.props.location.query.file || '',
   apps: [],
   showNav: this.props.location.query.file ? false : true,
   layout: 'row',
   cloneAppName: 'New Application',
   appName: 'Application Name',
   showSave: false
  }
 },
 urlListener: function(){
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(){
                       saveUnsaved();
  });
 },
        saveUnsaved: function(){
        }
```

The listener works fine and is being called whenever there is a change in the URL. However, the console says that the function I'm trying to call is not a function. I am new to React and any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: hi in listener function add this.saveUnsaved(); instead of saveUnsaved(); only

Comment: @spankajd I have tried that but the same error comes.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("hashchange", this.saveUnsaved)`;

Comment: @JordanBurnett I have tried that. Get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone had commented the answer which seemed to work for me, but the comment was removed before I could accept the answer. The correct way of doing it is

```js
{() => this.saveUnsaved();}
```

The arrow function apparently switches the context from "window" to "this"(the current component) internally. Without the arrow function, "this" would be referring to the "window" component.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me.

```
// ES6:
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('popstate', this.handleOnUrlChange, false)
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.handleOnUrlChange, false)
}
handleOnUrlChange = () => {
// your code
}
```

Comment: This should work. This answer could be improved by mentioning that the fat arrow `=>` on handleOnUrlChange is what makes the answer work. Alternately, you could use concise method syntax (ie: `handleOnUrlChange() { ... }` if you add this to your constructor: `this.handleOnUrlChange = this.handleOnUrlChange.bind(this)`.

Comment: If this is your first time experiencing the difference between using fat arrow or not and context of `this` changing illegally in React, you should make sure you pay attention because it will happen again. If you see a function call being ignored, think about `=>` and `.bind(this)`.